# Running a function when conditions are met?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building an application using Vuex and i'm not sure how to run a function when my data object meets a few user defined conditions.

```
<template>
 <swiper-slide v-for="(photon,key) in this.$store.state.photons" :key='key'>
  <ul>
   <li><label for="tempAlert">Temp exceeds</label><input v-model="photon.user.tempAlert" type="number"></li>
   <li><datetime type='datetime' v-model="photon.user.alertTime" use12-hour auto class="theme-orange">
    <label for="alertTime" slot="before">Notify at</label></datetime></li>
  </ul>
 </swiper-slider>
<template>


<script>
methods:{
  photonAlert(photon) {
    if(
      photon.user.alertTime>=new Date() &&
      photon.user.tempAlert>=photon.data.tempF[photon.data.tmepF.length-1][1]
    ) {
        this.sendnotification(photon)
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

What is the proper way to go about watching for changes and running a function when conditions are met?

Comment: have you tried [watch](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) ?

Answer (score 1):

Vue has a facility for this, `watch`:

```
watch: {
  photon: function (photon) {
    if(...
  },
```

As Jeff pointed out in comments, you are handling an object and may need to use `deep: true` to catch changes:

```
watch: {
  photon: {
    handler: function (photon) { if(... },
    deep: true
  }
},
```

Comment: if this is an object, you may need to also add `deep: true`. then the function would be under the `handler` property of the object.